# Selenium alternative to SendKeys() in Angular JS page

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium automation to automate a third party website. And to set the value of input fields in a form, I'm using the `SendKeys()` method. It is working without any issues but the problem is there are so many input fields in the form that it takes 5-6 seconds to fill 1 form, and I need to fill multiple forms like this. I know that it can also be automated using JavascriptExecutor like below

```js
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) driver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('mobileNum').value = '123456789'");
```

The problem, in this case, is the site is made in angular and just setting the value like this doesn't work properly, and the form keeps prompting that the values are blank (unlike by using `SendKeys()` when it works properly)

So what should be the correct way to fill the form quickly (like JavaScript) and correctly (like `SendKeys`)

Answer (score 1):

Usually frameworks such as Angular.js are attaching an event listener in-order to react (update the model behind this input), therefore it is not enough to change the value attribute, you need to trigger the listeners as well.
Each framework works with a different event, for inputs it can be `input` / `change`.

In order to do so, you can trigger it with:

```
document.getElementById('mobileNum').value = '123456789';
document.getElementById('mobileNum').dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }))
```

Comment: I also did that, the value of input by using this method is set correctly, but when I submit the form, the website I think is smart enough to detect automation, and it logs me out. But there are some chrome extensions which are automating that site without SendKeys() and they work perfectly fine

Comment: So maybe we need to add something more so that it look liike the values have been set by keystrokes only

Comment: PS: When I go to Event listeners of the input (from chrome developer tools), I can see the event listeners keydown and keypress attached, but they are not on that input node but `Window` node. So can we somehow trigger that?

Comment: Yes, you can change the `input` to `keypress` / `keydown`

Comment: With `input` only the value is changing properly... With `keydown` or `keypress`, it is appearing as blank only

Comment: Using keypress/ keydown is eventually writing the implementation of selenium's `SendKeys`. Try to trigger `change` event

Comment: `change` also doesn't change the value like `input`. And there should be some difference in the two, otherwise why it would work with selenium SendKeys and why not with keydown or keypress

Comment: Because when triggering keydown / keypress you should provide the char that was pressed.

Comment: Hi, I know it may be very late to resume discussion but I found out from decompiling an extension that the code `_0x76ed32['dispatchEvent'](new Event('blur')), $(_0x76ed32)[a0_0x3fed('0x9f')](a0_0x3fed('0x3b'), _0x5bf4db), _0x76ed32[a0_0x3fed('0xb3')](new Event('input'));` works fine, but I'm getting confused with the arguments. Can you help me to understand it?

Comment: Not sure how I can help... :}

Comment: maybe they're setting the value of input and dispatching `blur` and `input` events at the same time, am I right?

Comment: Looks like it triggers the blur & the input event, try to do the same...

Comment: I did it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63241466/explain-the-javascript but it didn't work. Maybe I'm not doing it correctly