# Explain the javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a website automation, and there is a form with an input field. I'm setting its value like below

```
var elem = document.getElementById('mobile');
elem.value = '1234567890';
elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur', { bubbles: true }));
```

After this when I click on submit button, it gives me an error that please fill the form manually and logs me out.

But I came across an extension, which does the exactly same job and without any error, when I decompiled the code, I found this line which sets the value of input correctly

```
_0x76ed32['dispatchEvent'](new Event('blur')), $(_0x76ed32)[a0_0x3fed('0x9f')](a0_0x3fed('0x3b'), _0x5bf4db), _0x76ed32[a0_0x3fed('0xb3')](new Event('input'));
```

I'm getting confused with the arguments, so can any javascript expert here provide a meaningful code for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks a bit like minimised code, where function call are often shortened by creating lookup tables, so you can save some bits on long function calls like `Element.dispatchEvent` and instead minimise it to `e[l(p)]`.

The variable `_0x76ed32` holds the reference to your input element.

```
_0x76ed32['dispatchEvent'](new Event('blur'))
```

This is a function call on your element. It is equivalent to the usual notation you see:

```
_0x76ed32.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'))
```

meaning it simply dispatches the blur event. This method to write a function call is typical if you don't know the name of the function and it's decided at runtime, e.g.

```
let func = 'dispatchEvent';
_0x76ed32[func](new Event('blur'))
```

Look up "reflection" to learn more about this.

The following code snippet is a good example for this:

```
a0_0x3fed('0x9f')
```

returns a function name which is then plugged into the following function call

```
$(_0x76ed32)[a0_0x3fed('0x9f')](a0_0x3fed('0x3b'), _0x5bf4db)
```

I assume it is setting the value of the input element `_0x76ed32`, but why the element is being wrapped `$(_0x76ed32)` and what the two function parameters are, cannot be told from just this line of code.
I assume it's similar to the native `setAttribute(name,value)` call.

and lastly you have the following code snippet:

```
_0x76ed32[a0_0x3fed('0xb3')](new Event('input'))
```

Here, `a0_0x3fed('0xb3')` again returns a function name. From inspecting the call, it's most likely `dispatchEvent`, which then dispatches the `input` event on the element `_0x76ed32`.

It might work something like this:

```js
let _0x76ed32 = document.querySelector("input"),
  fields = {
    '0xb3': "dispatchEvent",
    '0x3b': "value",
    '0x9f': "setAttribute"
  },
  a0_0x3fed = par => fields[par],
  _0x5bf4db = "new value :)";
  
// slightly changed the code
_0x76ed32[a0_0x3fed('0xb3')](new Event('input'));
_0x76ed32[a0_0x3fed('0x9f')](a0_0x3fed('0x3b'), _0x5bf4db);
_0x76ed32[a0_0x3fed('0xb3')](new Event('blur'));
```

```html
<input type="text" value="old value!" />
```

Final note: Your code should work perfectly fine, once you emit the events in the right order:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('mobile');
elem.value = '1234567890';
elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur', { bubbles: true }));
elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
```

```html
<input id="mobile" type="text" value="123" />
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Dispatching blur event, then setting value, then dispatching input event worked perfectly fine. One query, on some elements `keydown` and `keyup` events were also triggered. Can you also please mention the right way to trigger these events, and particularly their order