# difference between sendKeys() vs executeScript("arguments[0].value='testing')

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test our application which is in Angular. I wanted to know what is the difference between.
`WebElement stateSelect = driver.findElement(By.id("name")); stateSelect.sendKeys("Testing Angular");` and

```
WebElement stateSelect = driver.findElement(By.id("name")); ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value='testing angular interpolation';arguments[0].click()", stateSelect);
```

When i am testing with sendKeys interpolation on the particular webElement works, i.e it shows the updated value on interpolation while if i do the latter updating the value and try interpolation on that particular value it doesn't work. I would like to know how i could achieve sendKeys functionality using executeScript.

Comment: For testing purpose DO NOT use JavascriptExecutor to interact with web-page since it won't simulate real-user behavior!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebDriver click() vs JavaScript click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click)

Comment: This question was asked several times and has been answered a long time ago with great explanations

Comment: @Prophet this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62871182/15347640 answers my question.